# The last value of an array of array of ints overrides all other values

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to store 4 arrays in an array, and for some reason, the last value keeps overriding the previous three values. For example, if `123; 456; 789; 987` were inputted into the code below, `ipadr[0] - ipadr[4]` would all only store `123`. I've tested to make sure that `numConvert()` is working, and within `numConvert`, 4 different arrays of `ints` are returned, but only `numConvert(d)` is the `ipadr` array (stored 4 times).

Also, is my syntax / code correct in order for this function to return `ipadr` as an array of arrays (`int**`)? Why do you need to make it `static int*` when initializing the array?

I'm new to C and this has been really frustrating me. Any help would be incredibly appreciated. Thank you in advance!!

```
   int** ipConvert(int a, int b, int c, int d){
        static int* ipadr[4];
        ipadr[0]=numConvert(a);
        ipadr[1]=numConvert(b);
        ipadr[2]=numConvert(c);
        ipadr[3]=numConvert(d);
        return ipadr;
    }
```

numConvert code:

```
     int* numConvert(int dec) {
        static int hold[8];
        ...
        return hold;
    }
```

Comment: show the code for `numConvert`

Comment: @coderredoc added the code for numConvert!

Comment: @helloworld Change your code example to a [MCVE] as required here please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *hold* array is indeed overwritten after each call to numConvert, because it is a static area of 8 int.

Better use dynamic allocation with malloc, and have that function allocate 8 ints.

```
int* numConvert(int dec) {
    int *hold = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 8); // C++ need cast!
    int x = dec;
    for(int y=7;y>=0;y--){
        if(x%2==0 || x==0){
            hold[y]=0;
        }
        else{
            hold[y]=1;
        }
        x=x/2;
    }
    printf("\ntest loop: ");
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
      printf("%i", hold[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return hold;
}
```

then the returned values will have to be freed, after you don't need them anymore.

As for *static*, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c) explains it in details.

Comment: It's giving me this error now: `error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'` :(

Comment: What is your compiler? *malloc* should not be cast. Anyway, try `int *hold = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 8);`

Comment: I figured it out - I'm using C in a .cpp file. This worked—thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you write something in `hold` then return it, you basically overwrite the previous value. There is single instance of `hold` not multiple as you may be thinking.

`static` keyword you have used  without knowing the full functionality. It is not the same as automatic storage duration.

```
int* numConvert(int dec) {
    int *hold = malloc(sizeof *hold *8);
    if( hold == NULL){
       fprintf(stderr,"Error in malloc");
       exit(1);
    }
    int x = dec;
    ....
    ....
    return hold;
}
```

Free the dynamically allocated memory when you are done working with it.

#### What have we done here?

Dynamically allocated memory has lifetime beyond the scope of the function. So just like the `static` one it stays alive. But with contrary to the `static` variable each time a new chunk of memory is allocated. And for that we are not overwriting anything, which was the primary problem in your case.

#### One thing more..

`hold` is of automatic storage duration meaning every time we exit the function the `hold` is deallocated and then again when we call it we get to have a local variable named `hold`. So in each we get different instance. And that's why we return the address contained in `hold`. This memory whose address hold contains has lifetime beyond the scope of the function. So it stays unlike the local variable `hold` and we store this address in other function.

Comment: I tried this but it gives me this error if I don't use `static` :(    
`error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'`

Comment: @helloworld.: How do you compiler the program?

Comment: C++ requires you to cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: Exactly you are either running `c` code in `c++` file or using wrong compiler

Comment: @helloworld Sounds like you are using a c++ compiler. In that case prefer `new int[8];` to `malloc`. But in that case you should prefer `std::vector<int> hold(8);` to either.

Comment: Told yo..you are using c program in a cpp file... try to understand the solution provided and all the best @helloworld

Answer (score 0):

Declare your hold variable as instance variable rather then static variable like

```
 int* numConvert(int dec) {
    int hold[8];
```